# Transaction in cassandra and I am using gocql

Tags: cassandra, gocql

How can you make sure that one user insert is not influenced by another user?

Like transactions...

Do you use a batch job in combination with IF NOT EXISTS?

```
BEGIN UNLOGGED BATCH
INSERT INTO atable ("user1") value (10)
INSERT INTO atable ("user2") value (-10)
APPLY BATCH
```

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra introduced ['light weight' transaction](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/lightweight-transactions-in-cassandra-2-0) in 2.0, but it is not fully respect to ACID properties.

It uses Paxos to guarantee atomicity for such kind of 'light weight' transactions but it lacks the isolations solutions for handling concurrent transactions.

A solution could be implement two phase locking or some kind of optimistic concurrency control on top of Cassandra by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you were looking for. SOP adds ACID transactions on top of Cassandra & Redis.

See full source code here: https://github.com/SharedCode/sop
See article about it here: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/5376329/Scaleable-Objects-Persistence-SOP

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).